# How to enforce no-cycle constraint in domain-driven-design?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am still new in DDD. In the domain model, I have an aggregate for a `Component` which can either consist of sub-components or itself be a sub-component of another parent `Component`. In other words, I have a hierarchy of components.

Two actions are needed: `AddSubComponent()` and `AddToParent()`. How to enforce the invariant that no cycle shall exist in the hierarchy when executing these 2 actions? Shall it be enforced via domain events? Or just have reference to parents and children in the aggregate and then checking recursively within the aggregate itself the nested Components if the operation would create a cycle?

Note: I am using C# and persisting the domain model using EF Core.

**Edit**
I solved the problem by considering each component as an aggregate. Each has a reference to its parents and children.

`AddSubComponent(Component c)`
Checks if `c` is already a sub-component and returns or only adds `c` as sub-component after checking with parents of the component and the children of `c`. Then fires a domain event which is handled by the Application layer to verify the whole graph that it contains no cycles and also to call `c.AddToParent()`

`AddToParent(Component c)`
Does the same logic as the action above but adds only to parent and also fires a domain event which is handled at the Application layer as well only to call `parent.AddSubComponent()`.

This way calling any method would ensure the atomic consistency only for the aggregate and eventual consistency of the full hierarchy is ensured by the application layer. Also all those operations above are wrapped in a transaction. Therefore. only valid hierarchies are persisted eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather implement a one-way relationship in this case. When using events, like you mentioned, it would be trivial, as you can emit an event after executing `AddSubComponent`, so `AddToParent` will happen asynchronously, as a reaction. However, producing events in a system that just persist state, is not trivial, as you must avoid unreliable two-phase commits using an outbox or CDC.

If you only maintain the list of children for a parent, that won't be necessary. It might, of course, not fit to your context as cases like ensuring that a component has only one parent won't be possible inside the model itself and would require a domain service, which queries the component parents to see how many are there.

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce it right in the methods themselves.

**AddSubComponent**

During the Add SubComponent method, check if the component you are adding already exists as a child or a child of a child.

**AddToParent**

Call the "AddSubComponent" of the parent itself and the check will be done as described above.